# DOMDocument cannot load XML with internal DTD containing parameter entity

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, dtd

to validate an XML with its DTD i have use this php code

```
<?php
$myDoc = new DOMDocument;
$myDoc->load('file.xml', LIBXML_DTDLOAD);

// Enable user error handling
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
if (@$myDoc->validate())
{
    echo "Valid!\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Not valid:\n";
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    print_r($errors);
}
```

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note  [
<!ENTITY % Typo "#PCDATA | P | B ">
<!ELEMENT P (%Typo;)* >
<!ELEMENT B (%Typo;)* > 

<!ELEMENT note (to,from,heading,body)>    
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>    
<!ELEMENT from (%Typo;)>    
<!ELEMENT heading (#PCDATA)>    
<!ELEMENT body (#PCDATA)>    
]>

<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from><P>Tom</P></from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget!</body>
</note>
```

when i run the code i get this error at this line $myDoc->load('file.xml', LIBXML_DTDLOAD);

```
 ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected 
 expected '>' 
 internal error: xmlParseInternalSubset: error detected in Markup declaration 
 internal error: xmlParseInternalSubset: error detected in Markup declaration 
 DOCTYPE improperly terminated 
 Start tag expected, '<' not
```

what I understood that DOMDocument cannot load XML with internal DTD containing parameter entity because when I delete% Typo; the XML document will be loaded.
can you help me

Comment: Move the DTD to an external file and it will work as expected.